# Magento2 Change Payment method name/title dynamically

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

Magento2 Change the payment method title dynamically based on the text set from admin

I have created a test payment method using following reference.

```
https://webkul.com/blog/create-custom-payment-method-magento2/
```

I need to show the payment method title on checkout page based on a text box value set in admin. How can I achieve that? For e.g. as we can change the Flatrate & check/money order title from admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your system.xml as with below code and clear cache. you are able to set title in admin and it will dynamically changed on frontend too.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="payment">
                <group id="testpayment" translate="label" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Test Payment</label>
                    <field id="active" translate="label comment" sortOrder="1" type="select" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                        <label>Enable</label>
                        <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    </field>
                    <field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Payment Method Title</label>
                    </field>
                </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

hope this help :)

Comment: Hardluck not working...

Comment: it should work bro. don't know why not working for you

Comment: I got my mistake. It worked. Thanks

Comment: happy to hear it worked :)

Comment: Hello @Gohil, how can I display custom description that is added in admin under test payment method